# How does a cooking recipe and a software recipe (source code) differ from other kinds of data?

Tags: software, artistic-works

I understand that it is commonly believed that cooking recipes and "software recipes" (source codes) differ from other kinds of potentially-computer-memorized-data (such as a romantic song or a romantic book and so forth).

How does a *cooking recipe* and a *software recipe* (source code) differ from other kinds of data in general and works of art in particular?
Why are **they** more subjected to "copyleft" approaches than, say - songs, books, movies and series?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that they *are* more subject to "*copyleft approaches*"?  I've seen repositories of Creative Commons-licensed video / audio / musical / literary content.

Comment: I don't buy this claim for cooking recipes. For source code this could be true, but what means "more subjected to"? How do you measure this?

Comment: @MadHatter I never heard of copyright infringements in the context of recipes and source codes as I have in the context of books, images, videos, songs, etc. People might say "this is my recipe" or "this is software" and might even sue but not in the same magnitude from my experience.

Comment: @DocBrown my reply above.

Comment: @yolorolo I'm sorry, you've never heard of copyright infringement in source code?  Try [SCO vs. Novell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCO_Group,_Inc._v._Novell,_Inc.), for a start, and believe me, there is much, much more.  I agree that copyright violation is alleged much less often with respect to recipes, but [people do still try it](https://www.scribd.com/document/254222640/Tomaydo-Tomahhdo-v-Vozary-copying-recipes-opinion-pdf).

Comment: @MadHatter I have heard about it many times, it's just not as common as violation of copyrights for images, videos, books, articles and audios.

Comment: @yolorolo I understand you think that, but I don't agree.  It's your question; if you can't introduce some *data* to back up your position, you risk attracting answers that say simply "*they don't, they're not*".